# How to Quantify Utility/Pleasure/Pain using the Positive Real Numbers?

Tags: functions, real-numbers, utility

I am studying about [Cardinal Utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_utility) in Economics (or more generally, how to quantify **pleasure** and **pain**!)

Intuitively, I assign a positive number to pleasurable experiences, and a negative number to painful experiences:

- pleasurable experience $\rightarrow$ positive number
- painful experience $\rightarrow$ negative number
- greater the magnitude of the number $\rightarrow$ more intense is the pleasure or pain

But... is there anyway to transform this scale into the positive real numbers?

- more painful the experience $\rightarrow$ closer to zero
- more pleasurable the experience $\rightarrow$ larger positive number

That way, I won't need to worry about sign!

Comment: Sure. Define $f:\mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$ by taking all negative numbers to $\frac{1}{1+|x|}$, $0$ to $1$, and positive numbers to $x+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer mentioned by Good Morning Captain is great! If $U_\text{old}$ was my old utility scale, whose range is the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, then Captain's transformation:

$$U_\text{new} = f(U_\text{old}) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{1+|U_\text{old}|} &\text{for } U_\text{old} \leq 0\\ U_\text{old}+1 &\text{for } U_\text{old} > 0 \end{cases}$$

maps negative values of $U_\text{old}$ onto the unit interval $[0,1]$, while mapping the positive values onto $\mathbb{R}^+$.

An even simpler solution would be to just use the exponential transformation:

$$U_\text{new} = \exp(U_\text{old})$$

In both the cases (Captain's function and Exponential function):

- painful experiences $\rightarrow$ negative values in the $U_\text{old}$-scale $\rightarrow$ values in the range $[0,1)$ in the $U_\text{new}$-scale. More negative the experience, more close is the scale to 0.
- neutral experiences $\rightarrow$ 0 in the $U_\text{old}$-scale $\rightarrow$ 1 in the $U_\text{new}$-scale
- pleasurable experiences $\rightarrow$ positive values in the $U_\text{old}$-scale $\rightarrow$ values in the range $(1,+\infty)$ in the $U_\text{new}$-scale